# Finding roots of a function in an interval

Tags: calculus, functions, polynomials, roots

> Does the equation $x^3-12x+2=0$ have three solutions in the interval $[-4,4]$?

We know that this is a continuous function because it's a polynomial, and so we can use the **Intermediate Value Theorem** to do this problem:

> If $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, let $M$ be any number between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$. Then there exists a number $c$ such that:
>
> 1) $a<c<b$
>   2) $f(c)=M$

If we define $M=0$, $a=-4$ and $b=4$, then $-4<c<4$ and $f(-4)<0<f(4)$.

Compute $f(-4)$ and $f(4)$ to show that $f(-4)<0<f(4)$
$\implies -14=f(-4)<0<f(4)<18$.

So I've shown that $M$ is between $f(-4)$ and $f(4)$, and thus there must be some number $c$ such that $f(c)=M=0$.

Is all of this correct?
How do I show that there are **three** solutions (roots) in this interval?
Thank you.

Comment: Quadratic equations can have at most two solutions in any interval.  Indeed, if we count roots according to multiplicity, a polynomial of degree $n$ will have exactly $n$ roots in the entire complex plane, which properly includes all real intervals.

Comment: I expect that the correct equation is $x^3-12x+2=0$, which does have three roots in $[-4,4]$.

Comment: @lhf thanks, that's what I meant, i fixed it to $x^3$.

Comment: @user436158 : hardmath's comment shows there are _at most_ three such solutions (indeed, there are at most three distinct complex solutions).  I would try plugging in the numbers -4, -3, ...,4 into the LHS of the equation and seeing if the function $f(x)=x^3-12x+2$ changes sign 3 times between $x=-4$ and $x=4$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No quadratic equation can have three roots in any interval.

I expect that the correct equation is $x^3-12x+2=0$, which does have three roots in $[-4,4]$ because $f(-4)<0$, $f(0)>0$, $f(1)<0$, $f(4)>0$. By the Intermediate Value Theorem, each sign variation gives you at least one root in that interval.

Comment: thanks, but how did you get those values: $f(1)<0$, etc?

Comment: @user436158, I just evaluated $f(x)$ for $x=-4,-3,\dots,3,-4$ and chose nice ones.